# Access to offline Unity3d API reference in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I'll use offline Unity3d reference in Visual Studio but it always open built-in browser.
Is there any way to open local reference in VS?

Comment: Have you read through [this forum thread](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/api-help-shortcut-in-visual-studio.344137/)?

Comment: This thread don't give me answer 4 my question. I have correctly connected Visual Studio and I also find how to make special toolbar, but it send me to online reference, not to local :/